# Create PhoneGap project in Ubuntu and command line

Tags: ubuntu, cordova

I wanted a little "play" the PhoneGap framework on Ubuntu , so I installed the necessary tools (ADT , Java, Node.js , PhoneGap , etc. . ), But from the very beginning haunt me some bad luck. I created a project command:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
```

then moved on to the project directory command 'cd ' and I wanted to add the Android platform to project command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Unfortunately , the first time I received an error in the form of missing libraries - when I installed it I received another error (actually two errors ) that reads:

1. `error while loading share libraries : libstdc + + . so.6 : can not open shared object file: No such file or directory`
2. `build.xml : 653 : The Following error occured while executing this line : ... build.xml : 698 : null returned : 127`

And also I get : BUILD FAILED . Does anyone know how to fix it. Or maybe it at all, I make bad design (trying to imitate official guide -> http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

Please help and best regards.

Comment: You have to install Apache ANT and set ANT_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and tracked this down. 
In the process of adding the platform support cordova calls the javascript file `$HOME/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.2.0/bin/create` which includes `$HOME/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.2.0/bin/lib/create.js` which then calls `ant jar` in the directory `$HOME/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.2.0/framework`. If you do this manually, you receive this error message

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] [your path to adt-bundle]/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The solution on my Ubuntu 13.10 was to do a `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`. 
Now the

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
```

worked smoothly. Hope it works for you, too.